# In Highcharts, is it possible to enable all markers on hover?

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of series with markers disabled, and I want to enable all the markers on serie hover, not individual point ans the doc states here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.states.hover

The closest thing I had is this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                 enabled: true,
                 marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this I hoped that the markers are all off, and when hovering all the markers are showed, as I thought that the series `markers.enabled` was set to true, but as the docs I shown above states, this is not what happens.

I would like to do this to show the user where he can mouseover to see the next/prev tooltip, as the markers are not equidistant.

Is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use series.events.mouseOver and series.events.mouseOut functions for updating your series, so you will show or hide your markers.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
  stickyTracking: false,
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    events: {
      mouseOver: function() {
        this.update({
          marker: {
            enabled: true
          }
        });
      },mouseOut: function() {
        this.update({
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/hgbz7kg6/

Comment: Altough this is a valid answer for one series, on charts with multiple overlapping series leads to problems: https://streamable.com/bf3t

Comment: Could you post live example of this issue?

Comment: On monday I'll do so. I have to check the code on my workplace.

Comment: I think that you may have some problems with tooltip: shared set to true. Here you can see an example of two series chart with shared tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/hgbz7kg6/2/

Comment: Yes, that hack is a problem. I would like to have that functionality built-in.

Comment: I mean, I don't have shared tooltips. Here you have a fiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Llorx/hgbz7kg6/3/ When two series overlap, there's a graphical problem. Also, logging a lot of errors on console.

Comment: You can change my idea a little bit to avoid these errors and the problem you had: http://jsfiddle.net/hgbz7kg6/5/

Comment: This... is... awesome. Don't saw the markerGroup parameter. I can also implement it in another situation, where I was doing update() to show and hide markers too, but eating a bit of CPU on large charts because of redraws. How can I upvote again for this answer? xD

Comment: Happy to hear that my example worked for you. I am not sure if multiple upvotes are possible ;)